# Intercept from different bases possible in X-Com Enemy Unknown?

Tags: xcom-enemy-unknown

I tried to intercept some UFO in Asia. It got away. I didn't have any other Interceptor in Asia, but the UFO was flying to Europe where I had two more.

Is there any way to send the Interceptors from Europe after the UFO which was originally spotted in Asia?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

No, there isn't. You can transfer interceptors to different continents from the Hangar menu, but that takes 3 days, by which time the UFO will have escaped.

Comment: Well, this is not the answer I hoped for, but still...
Do you have a source for your answer? (meaning: Are you really sure or did you just also not find an way to do it?)

Comment: I'm as sure as somebody who doesn't have access to the source code can be.

Comment: @StampedeXV kotekzot is right, there is simply no way to intercept from a different base